# RGB from a Parameter value

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I get a Low RGB Red value to a High RGB Red value using a Parameter value which is increasing in WPF c#.

```
// cnange color
r *= 1.5;
g *= 3.33;
rectangleSecond.Stroke 
     = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)r, (byte)g, (byte)b));
```

Comment: what do you want exactly ?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by low red and high red? Give some examples.

Comment: Probably your requirement is better explained/handled in a HSV colorspace.

Comment: Why would you multiply `r` and `g` without doing any bounds checking? What if `g` was between 77 (>255/3.33) and 255 to start with?

Answer (score -1):

Convert your color from `RGB` color space to `HSV` (Hue/Saturation/Value) color space. Do all modifications there, like "more Saturation" and convert back to `RGB` space.